# how do you fix this string index issue?

Tags: python

i keep getting a string index error, although im pretty sure i did everything correct

here is my code:

```
alphaletters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
keyboards = []

xalpha = [-40, 0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280, 320,
          -20, 20, 60, 100, 140, 180, 220, 260, 300,
          -30, 10, 50, 90, 130, 170, 210]

yalpha = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,
          40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,
          80,80,80,80,80,80,80]

for i in range(len(alphaletters)):
  keyboards.append(Button(window, text=alphaletters[i], width=1, height=1,font=("arial","12","bold"),fg="black",command=lambda: entry.insert(alphaletters[i])))
  keyboards[i-1].place(x=xalpha[i-1]+280,y=yalpha[i-1]+140)
```

here is my error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 44, in <lambda>
    keyboards.append(Button(window, text=alphaletters[i], width=1, height=1,font=("arial","12","bold"),fg="black",command=lambda: entry.insert(alphaletters[i])))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

could anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

`entry.insert(alphaletters[i])` is looking for an index inside the `entry` widget to place the string. This code is making your string the index because it is the first argument. To put `alphaletter[i]` into `entry` at the beginning (first character in the entry string):

`entry.insert(0,alphaletters[i])`

at the end:

`entry.insert('end',alphaletters[i])`

Comment: Wouldn't that instead be a `TypeError` complaining about the number of arguments?

Comment: Just tested it: `tkinter.Entry().insert('c')` got me `TypeError: Entry.insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`.

Comment: So you might be right that that will fix their **next** issue, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: Not a type error becuse it is all string - the entry index is a string as well. And the question is about a string index error so this does answer

Comment: The number of arguments doesn't come into it because the interpreter doesn't get that far - it breaks at checking out the first argument. This is why your test gets a type error it is now looking for the next argument.. The index 'c' is accepted because ```c``` is an abbreviation  of ```char```. Your test won't work further on because just ```c``` is not enough - you'd need a a full index of ```line.char```.

Comment: amended last comment - The number of arguments doesn't come into it because the interpreter doesn't get that far - it breaks at checking out the first argument. This is why your test gets a type error, it is now looking for the next argument.. The index 'c' is accepted because it is type string for the entry index. Your test won't work further on because just ```c``` is not enough - you'd need a a full index of ```line.char```.

Comment: arrgh - another comment fix. I confused ```text``` with ```entry```. ```entry```` doesn't have lines so the entry index is a string designating (number, anchor, end, insert, sel.first, sel.last, @number). Check out https://www.tcl.tk/ docs